# VBA calculate MD5 hash on file contents

Tags: vba, ms-access, md5, ms-access-2013

I need a VBA routine to calculate the MD5 hash of a file's contents. I located some examples (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826302/how-to-get-the-md5-hex-hash-for-a-file-using-vba)) but I found that they crashed when the filename contained certain Unicode characters, so I am trying to tweak the code to avoid that.

This code does not result in an error, but it also doesn't return the correct MD5 hash. What's wrong?

```
Public Function FileToMD5Hex(sFileName As String) As String
    Dim enc
    Dim bytes
    Dim outstr As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
    'Convert the string to a byte array and hash it
    bytes = GetFileBytes(sFileName)
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((bytes))
    'Convert the byte array to a hex string
    For pos = 1 To LenB(bytes)
        outstr = outstr & LCase(Right("0" & Hex(AscB(MidB(bytes, pos, 1))), 2))
    Next
    FileToMD5Hex = outstr
    Set enc = Nothing
End Function

Private Function GetFileBytes(path As String) As Byte()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim fil As Object
    Set fil = fso.GetFile(path)

'    Dim fpga As Variant
    GetFileBytes = fil.OpenAsTextStream().Read(fil.Size)

    Set fil = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some chars sequences that `Scripting.FileSystemObject` can't process properly as `TextStream`.

Use `ADODB.Stream` ActiveX to retrieve array of bytes from file. It works perfectly with both text and binary types of data, also it allows to change charset of the string (`FSO` only works with ASCII and Unicode, and only with files).

```
Function GetFileBytes(strPath As String) As Byte()
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile (strPath)
        GetFileBytes = .Read()
    End With
End Function
```

Another one ActiveX processing binary data is `SAPI.spFileStream`. One of the most significant advantages - it allows to load only the part of the file to the memory (in some cases when comparing large files it can help drastically increase performance, checking md5 by chunks).

```
Function GetFileBytes(strPath As String) As Byte()
    Dim arrContent As Variant
    With CreateObject("SAPI.spFileStream")
        .Open strPath, 0
        .Read arrContent, CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(strPath).Size
        .Close
    End With
    GetFileBytes = arrContent
End Function
```

Comment: Nice code (I will be using the `ADODB.Stream` instead of Open #F for Binary Read` and a `Get` from now on). **However, there's a missing component:** do you have an example of a System.Security.Cryptography function loading successive chunks of bytes into a single hash calculation?

Comment: Update: user Florent B. posted an answer with data passed in chunks to the MD5 hashing service in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36331066/362712)  - This would work very nicely with your `SAPI.spFileStream` implementation.