# Timestamp of last workbook modification after it was saved (not the last saved time)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to know when an Excel workbook was last modified after it was saved.

Lets say I saved the file, and after I saved it, I modified something that triggered the `workbook.Saved = false`. How to get the timestamp of this last change made to the workbook ?

I am aware of the `ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")` but this only gives me the timestamp of the saved file and does not take in account any modifications made after the save.

Anyone know if this is possible? I found nothing online, and no BuiltinDocumentProperty has this information.

Comment: You could keep track of it with the [`SheetChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event maybe.

Comment: It is an option, but unfortunately this does not track any other changes such as VBA code changes, for example. There are many other workbook changes that trigger the `workbook.saved = false` and do not fire the `SheetChange` event

Comment: I don't have any other ideas then... you may be out of luck, maybe not, hopefully not.

Comment: There is nothing like it, no. Why do you need this? You could hack up something with handling `SelectionChange` and `SheetActivate` to evaluate whether `.Saved` is `False`; I wouldn't think that's reliable, but probably the closest you can get.

Comment: I am working on an automatic backup module, and need to know if I already have a backup for the latest edits before user saves the file.

Comment: Why not just make a new backup regardless?

Comment: I could, but my system does a backup every 5 minutes, so then even if I the user doesn´t make any change, I will have 20 backups/hour, which in a full work day will take me around 2gb because of the workbook size. It is an option but I am hoping to find an alternative solution that makes a backup only when the workbook was actually modified but not saved

Comment: You can condition the backup by preliminary checking of `.Saved` property, then... So, the backup will be done only if `.Saved` property returns `False`. Supposing that the backup is done using VBA...

Comment: Do you know git and is turning autosave on an option? If so, you could hack up git source control to handle the backups (repository could be a private, remote repository on GitHub), basically treating the workbook binary diff as a changeset/commit, and then you could easily "restore" the workbook "as of" any of these commits - and your file system only ever needs a single copy of the file. Actually you could hook it up to a AfterSave handler and make a new commit/"checkpoint" every time the file is saved, through autosave or not.

Comment: Since you can calculate MD5 on a file using VBA: make a backup, then check the MD5 for that backup against the previous backup: if there's no change then delete the backup.

Comment: MD5 in VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826302/how-to-get-the-md5-hex-hash-for-a-file-using-vba