# Securely opening external applications

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 application that in parts opens other applications. These applications can be created by approved third parties for integration purposes.
I am trying to find a way that I can open these securely and ensure the application that gets opened is the one intended.
I want to ensure the .exe cant be replaced by another with the same name. The main application has access to an SQL database. So I was thinking of a hashed key but I then run into a problem where I would need to create a new release for each new integration.

Any suggestions would be fantastic!

Comment: How about having a "Register/Update approved application" option in your program? It calculates the hash of a approved application that should be added and stores it in a database. Before launching any registered application, you calculated the hash of it and compare it to the one stored.

Comment: If I understand, you want to make sure the program you're running is really the program you think it is.  I can think of three possible levels...  1)  Verify file name, path, and size.  Possibly even file version with a `GetFileVersionInfoSize` API.  Low overhead, low bar to pass, but better than nothing.  2) MD5 Hash (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826302/how-to-get-the-md5-hex-hash-for-a-file-using-vba). 3)  Verify certificate signature.  Accomplishes #2 but lets you publish new versions that will also pass.

Comment: Is this intended just as a "correctness" measure? e.g., in case the programmer mistakenly has the wrong EXE in place? Or for actual security?  If the latter then I think a limitation of any local mechanism to verify the secondary EXE is that your primary program may have been compromised.

Comment: You can use code-signing certificates. You can issue code-signing certificates from your own CA. You can check if an executable is signed by a certificate that is issued by a CA with predefined public key. You can sign an executable with multiple certificates. You can sign an executable by a "regular" code-signing certificate and your own issued certificates simultaneously.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for everyone's input I am going to review these but the certificates seems a good idea.